# Getting image from resources folder in the project

Tags: c#

I want to get image file path into resources project folder but i don't know how.

```
Image newImage = Image.FromFile(Boosty.Properties.Resources.soft);
```

Comment: It's an imported PNG file in the project. It return the bitmap and i want the string path of the image

Comment: Isn't the parameter for `Image.FromFile(...)` the path you want? It seems do be, assuming it is this method.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromfile?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code for getting an Icon that is embedded in the resources of a WinForms exe:

```
Assembly thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string appName=thisAssembly.GetName().Name;
normalIcon=new Icon(thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(appName+".Clipboard.ico"));
```

The key part is the call to `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`

The other key is that the file is registered this way in the Properties for the file:

| Advanced |  |
| --- | --- |
| Build Action | Embedded Resource |
| Copy to Output Directory | Do Not Copy |

Comment: This only work for Icons?

Comment: No, I only have code for icons.  It should work for any resource.  The `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream` call pulls the file out of the assembly's resources as a stream.  You use that to initialize whatever you want